# Styling Jekyll website with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to set up a website using Jekyll and GitHub Pages (first-timer), and most importantly, to style it with Bootstrap.

You can check what I have already done:

- GitHub repository: https://github.com/thibaudclement/wallaby
- GitHub page: http://thibaudclement.github.io/wallaby/ (check gh-pages branch)

Also, I followed [this tutorial](http://getpocket.com/a/read/904495931) to import Bootstrap into the Jekyll structure.

Layouts and includes seem to work just fine, but I don't understand why my index.html does not get "styled" as it should, fetching information into the css/style.css file.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to your css file is incorrect - it's not loading if you check your browser console

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - http://thibaudclement.github.io/wallaby/style/site.css"

Answer (score 0):

In _config.yml, you need to set `baseurl: /wallaby`.

And use `{{ site.baseurl }}` to load resources like this :

```
 <link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />.
```

See [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/).